# RSpec: execute the same expectation under different circumstances

Tags: rspec

I want to make sure that an element on my website is only displayed when logging in.

This is how I achieve it at the moment:

```
it 'displays statistics when logged in' do
  expect {
    login_as(create :user)
    refresh_page
  }.to change {
    page.has_content? 'Statistics'
  }.from(false).to true # I know, "to true" is redundant here, but I like it to be explicit
end
```

This somehow feels clumsy. Especially, when the spec fails, I don't get the nice error message I usually get when doing an `expect(page).to have_content 'Statistics'`, I just get something like "expected result to have changed from false to true, but did not change" which isn't very informative.

I know there are shared examples, but they feel a bit too much for this case.

I tried something like the following, but didn't succeed either:

```
it 'displays statistics when logged in' do
  expect(expect_to_have_content_statistics).to raise_error

  login_as(create :user)
  refresh_page

  expect_to_have_content_statistics
end

def expect_to_have_content_statistics
  expect(page).to have_content 'Statistics'
end
```

Any ideas? I don't want to write the expectation 2 times, as this is very error prone.

Comment: Why not write `expect(page).to_not have_content('Statistics')` for the first expectation?

Comment: @stytown: quote from my post "I don't want to write the expectation 2 times, as this is very error prone." This leads to false-positives very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing two different cases - would suggest to separate them.

```
describe 'statistics' do

  def have_statistics
    have_content('Statistics')
  end

  before { visit_statistics_page }

  it { expect(page).to_not have_statistics }

  it 'displays statistics when logged in' do
    login_as(create :user)
    expect(page).to have_statistics
  end
end
```

Comment: The thing is that I exactly don't want to do this, as negative tests (`expect(page).not_to ...`) will pass all the time, even when I change the title "Statistics" to something different and I forget to update the "negative test". So I'd really like to write the expectation only once and execute it twice: once it's expected to pass, once it's expected to fail.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim: DRYing up the `have_content('Statistics`)` matcher should cover that case.

Comment: How would you dry it up?

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I will check it out.

Comment: This works. Still, I feel this is error prone, as the specs are coupled loosely, and chances are they are torn apart while being refactored, stuff gets deleted, and suddenly you have inexhaustive specs and false-positives. I mark this as the correct answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the spec out into two `context` blocks since you are testing two distinct use cases.  Also, rather than do a hard-coded text-based `have_content` check on the `page`, do you have some kind of `<div>` or `<span>` tag wrapping the statistics content (with perhaps a `class` or `id` of `statistics` or something)?  If not, you might want to consider one, if so, then consider changing your spec to check whether that selector is present or not depending on whether a user is logged in:

```
RSpec.feature 'Statistics' do
  context 'when user is not logged in' do
    before do
      visit statistics_path # or whatever path this is
    end

    it 'does not display the statistics' do
      expect(page).to_not have_selector('.statistics')
    end
  end

  context 'when user is logged in' do
    before do
      login_as(create :user)
      visit statistics_path # or whatever path this is
    end

    it 'displays the statistics' do
      expect(page).to have_selector('.statistics')
    end
  end
end
```